# Error Createconnection (error en Promesa(? )

Tags: javascript, nodejs, base-de-datos, mariadb, refactoring

estoy aprendiendo NodeJs, al principio me conecto bien, pero al momento de Refactorizar el código me fue imposible conectarme a la base de datos (estoy usando MariaDB con HeidiSQL).

**El error que me tira en consola es:**
PoolPromise {
_events: [Object: null prototype] { error: [Function (anonymous)] },
_eventsCount: 1,
_maxListeners: undefined,
[Symbol(kCapture)]: false }

**Y en el navegador:**
{"error":"Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'createConnection')"}

**Código del Config/Index.js:**

```
const dotenv = require("dotenv"); 
dotenv.config(); 
const config = { 
dev: process.env.NODE_ENV != "production", 
port: process.env.PORT || 3000, 
databaseUrl: process.env.DATABASE_URL, }  
module.exports = config;
```

**Código del lib/connect.js:**

```
const config = require("../config"); 
const mariadb = require("mariadb"); 
const pool = mariadb.createPool(config.databaseUrl); 
module.exports = pool;
```

**Código del archivo .env:**

```
DATABASE_URL = 'mariadb://root:1234@localhost:3300/heroes?connectionLimit=5000'
```

**Código del js del repositorio:**

```
const connect = require("../lib/connect"); 
const pool = connect.pool; 
async function getAvengers() { 
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => { 
        let conn; 
        try { 
            conn = await pool.createConnection(); 
            const query = await conn.query("SELECT * FROM avengers"); 
            resolve(query); } 
        catch (error) { 
            reject(error); 
        } finally { 
            if (conn) conn.end(); } }); }
 module.exports = { getAvengers, }
```

**Código del js service:**

```
const avengersRepository = require("../repositories/avengersRepository")

async function getAvengers(){
    return await avengersRepository.getAvengers();
}
 module.exports = {
    getAvengers,
}
```

**Código del js router:**

```
const express = require("express"); 
const avengersService = require("../services/avengersService"); 
const router = express.Router(); 
router.get("/", getAvengers); 
module.exports = router;

async function getAvengers(req, res) {
    try {
        const avengers = await avengersService.getAvengers();
        res.status(200).json(avengers);
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json({ error: error.message });
    }
};
```

**Código del index.js:**

```
const express = require("express") 
const config = require("./config/index"); 
const avengersRouter = require("./routes/avengersRouter");
const app = express();
const port = config.port;
app.use(express.json());
app.use("/avengers", avengersRouter);
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server running at http://localhost:${port}`))
```

Lamento lo largo pero no quise dejar sin aportar parte de código que pueda ayudar en la respuesta. Desde ya gracias, y felicidades para todos.

Answer (score 1):

He logrado solucionarlo, el problema estaba en el código del repositorio, estaba tratando de importar la propiedad **pool** del módulo connect, siendo que "pool" es lo único que exporto del mismo.

El código del repositorio js quedaría así:

```
const connect = require("../lib/connect"); 
async function getAvengers() { 
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => { 
        let conn; 
        let pool = connect;
        try { 
            conn = await pool.createConnection(); 
            const query = await conn.query("SELECT * FROM avengers"); 
            resolve(query); } 
        catch (error) { 
            reject(error); 
        } finally { 
            if (conn) conn.end(); } }); }
```